# using jdatechooser to display duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql-server, swing, date

Guys i have a table called product_inflow containing details of products and when they arrive to be added to the stock.Due to this,several dates may appear more than once for different items. I want to search through the database and view all items that share same dates of arrival in the a Jtable where all the entries are displayed

1>  I tried using the "Date =" syntax but it only gives just one out of the many items that have the same date .

**sql = "select Date,ItemDescription,Unit,QuantityIn from productinflow where Date  ='"+((JTextField)fromDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()+"';**

2> Same happened when i tried using 2 different Jdatechoosers to select items in a range of different dates which would inlcude duplicates dates.It also displayed a few of the items ... I want the duplicates to show up and the queries i used arent working so any help with this would be appreciated.

**sql = "select Date,ItemDescription,Unit,QuantityIn from productinflow where Date  between '"+((JTextField)fromDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()+"' and  '"+((JTextField)toDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()+"';**

[table will all data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNwo1.png)

[output when i set date ranges to 25/01/2017 to 30/01/2017 which would have give 14 results including all duplicate dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqRfB.png)

Comment: try changing the format of date in query you have written , sql has YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: Ok .ill try and see